# Electron Application Cannot find Squirrel

Tags: javascript, auto-update, electron

I am writing an Electron Application for Windows with auto update capabilities, using the [autoUpdater API](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/auto-updater.md).

```
app.on('ready', function(){
  console.log('application emitted "ready"');

  var autoUpdater = require('auto-updater');

  autoUpdater.setFeedURL(releaseUrl);
  console.log('releaseUrl: ' + releaseUrl);

  autoUpdater
    .on('error', function(){
      console.log(arguments);
    })
    .on('checking-for-update', function() {
      console.log('Checking for update');
    })
    .on('update-available', function() {
      console.log('Update available');
    })
    .on('update-not-available', function() {
      console.log('Update not available');
      createWindow();
    })
    .on('update-downloaded', function() {
      console.log('Update downloaded');
    });

  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();

});
```

So far the only event that I can get to fire is the error event and it logs out this message:

```
{ '0': [Error: Can not find Squirrel],
  '1': 'Can not find Squirrel' }
```

Am I supposed to install some Squirrel package? I cant find anything in the documentation about installing extra packages for Squirrel.

This is in electron v0.36.0

Comment: Hi, did you make auto update work?

Comment: @Ng2-Fun yes, for Windows the application needs to be packaged into an installer executable using grunt electron installer https://github.com/electron/grunt-electron-installer

Comment: Thanks @user231300. Auto update works somehow. But I pop up a window to let use choose if he wants to update now or later in ''update-available''. I can pop up the window using `dialog.showMessageBox({ message: "Update available. Do you want to update now or later",
   buttons: ["Update", "Not Now"] }, function (choice) {
    if (choice === 0) {...} else {...}`, but the problem is whenever there is new update, it will auto download it. I can't stop it if the user choose not to install now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your app isn't installed, calling out to Squirrel won't work. You need to have an installed app.

Comment: Is there an easy way to check if your app is installed? as opposed to running it via `electron .`?

Comment: `process.execPath.match(/[\\\/]electron-prebuilt/)`

Comment: but how to have an installed app while developing auto updater? it's obvious that it's not logical to package app during development and test it